# How Display large Text in Page's like Book?

Tags: java, android, textview

First let me say that I'm very new to android development  and now work in app read `.txt` file in Cd-card and display it by page

need know how I can set the text in page's and Browse it

*Ex : Page1 <-> Page2 <-> Page3 <-> Page4 <-> ..... For End Text*

I watched many problems here but I did not know the answer

Comment: improve your questions

Comment: what do you mean by that "text page and Browse page by page"?

Comment: Ex : Page1 <-> Page2 <-> Page3 <-> Page4 <-> ..... For End Text

Comment: do you mean add paging to your activity?

Comment: @ mohammad rababah yes need it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use [ViewPager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html)

Listing of main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <TextView android:text="Page 1" android:id="@+id/textViewHeader"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center" android:padding="10dip" android:textStyle="bold"></TextView>
    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:id="@+id/viewPager" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Setting up the ViewPager

```
ViewPager viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewPager);
MyPagerAdapter adapter = new MyPagerAdapter(this);
viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
```

The PagerAdapter

```
@Override
public void destroyItem(View view, int arg1, Object object) {
         ((ViewPager) view).removeView((View)object);
}
@Override
public int getCount() {
          return views.size();
}
@Override
public Object instantiateItem(View view, int position) {
           View view = views.get(position);
           ((ViewPager) view).addView(view);
           return view;
}
@Override
public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object) {
           return view == object;
}
```

good luck